# Class PHP methods get and set

Tags: php, class, static

I have this class:

```
<?php
    class Test {

        private $_ID;
        private $_NAME;
        private $_AGE;

        public function setID() { $this->_ID++; }
        public function getID() { return $this->_ID; }

        public function setNAME($element) { $this->_NAME = $element; }
        public function getNAME() { return $this->_NAME; }

        public function setAGE($element) { $this->_AGE = $element; }
        public function getAGE() { return $this->_AGE; }

        public function addUser($name, $age) {
            Test::setID();
            Test::setNAME($name);
            Test::setAGE($age);

            echo "OK";
        }
    }
?>
```

I want to create objects of this class, and assign the data with the function addUser like this:

```
$test = new Test();
$test:: addUser("Peter", "12"); but I have errors.
```

I have this errors:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method Test::addUser() should not be
>   called statically in /var/www/public/testManu.php on line 13
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Test::setID() should not be called
>   statically in /var/www/public/class/Test.php on line 18
>
> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   /var/www/public/class/Test.php on line 8

I have problems with variable scope. Could somebody tell me what it is my problem????

Comment: can you tell a bit more about the problem?

Comment: "I have problems with variable scope" is too vague - what symptoms do you see?  Errors? Unexpected behaviour? Any error messages?

Comment: what is Teprohelper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
 ...
 public function addUser($name, $age) {
        $this->setID();
        $this->setNAME($name);
        $this->setAGE($age);

        echo "OK";
    }
 ...
```

Calling like `Classname::function()` is only valid for static methods. You have a dedicated instance which need to be addressed with the construct `$this->function()`.

And thus:

```
   ...
  $test->addUser("Peter", "12"); but I have errors.
```

Comment: His class is called `Test` the other one he used is `Teprohelper`. So the usage is probable (you dont know what `Teprohelper` is, but with names its not the `Test` class therefore cannot be changed into `$this`;

Comment: I have corrected the description of my mistake, now is correct

Comment: @Seti Just an assumption that `Teprohelper` is miss typed and it should be the same class/object as you may see by the methods which are called - defined in class `Test`

Comment: @Seti yepp. He's messed up with object references

Comment: Yep, he fixed that, but still. What is usage of class that can store only one user at its best?

Answer (score 2):

```
$test = new Test();
$test -> addUser("Peter", "12"); #now no errors
```

Comment: But still. Can you tell us what you want to achieve exactly? You are using two classes here. One `Test` and one `Teprohelper`...

Comment: IGNORE TEPSOHELPER IT'S A TYPO!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php
    class Test {

        private static $_ID = 1;
        private static $_NAME;
        private static $_AGE;

        public static function setID() { self::$_ID++; }
        public static function getID() { return self::$_ID; }

        public static function setNAME($element) { self::$_NAME = $element; }
        public static function getNAME() { return self::$_NAME; }

        public static function setAGE($element) { self::$_AGE = $element; }
        public static function getAGE() { return self::$_AGE; }

        public static function addUser($name, $age) {
            self::setID();
            self::setNAME($name);
            self::setAGE($age);

            echo "OK";
        }
    }

$test = new Test(); /*You don't need to instantiate the class 
                      because you're calling a static function*/
$test:: addUser("Peter", "12"); but I have errors.
?>
```

Comment: I think its not what he wanted to achieve... Now he have one class that can store one user.... And thats all...

Comment: Should work, but the question is whether he actually wants static methods on a non-instance or an instance. As he's instantiating the object, I assume that it shouldn't be static.

Comment: I have this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '++' (T_INC) in /var/www/public/class/Test.php on line 8

Comment: You need to assign a number to `private static $_ID`  I thought you already had set it, I've updated my answer